# When I'm bitten, what am I?

Tags: riddle

In an attempt to bump up the difficulty of my riddles so far, I'm going to be a little more vague with this one.

> When I'm bitten, you will suffer.
>   When I'm precious, you will suffer no more.
>   When I'm used, you will never see me again.

What am I?

Comment: A lot of body parts would fit the first and third lines...

Comment: I think that is related to some medicines

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would it be

> a bullet, maybe?

When I'm bitten, you will suffer.

> yes, when I bite the bullet, I suffer indeed from something

When I'm precious, you will suffer no more.

> a silver bullet is a solution to a problem, perhaps to the same problem that made me bite the bullet earlier

When I'm used, you will never see me again.

> yes, if you use a litteral bullet on me, I might be killed

I enjoyed that one a lot, thanks !

Comment: Yes!  Precisely the answer I was looking for.  Good work.  Though also for the third clue, I was thinking along the lines of shooting a bullet and never having it come back, but your reasoning works too.

Comment: @Cubicon Uhm, I don't like very much riddles that rely on idioms or folklore of a particular country, for instance I would never be able to know that _bite the bullet_ has the same meaning of the italian [_stringere i denti_](https://translate.google.it/#it/en/stringere%20i%20denti) (which literally means _thighten your teeth_ ), but I have to admit that this is a good one.

Comment: Same goes for [_silver bullet_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bullet#Idiomatic_usage).

Comment: @Narmer I suppose, but as this is an English-language riddle, I don't think knowing common English idioms is an unreasonable requirement.  Indeed, riddles in general are very tightly bound to the language in which they're written, and knowledge of the intricacies of that language is often required to solve them.

Comment: I thought of bullet, but was sure it didn't fit the last two lines :-(

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a

> Coin

When I'm bitten, you will suffer.

> Bit a coin and tell me how you feel!

When I'm precious, you will suffer no more.

> A gold coin is worth a lot of money. If you have one, you won't suffer poverty.

When I'm used, you will never see me again.

> After you've spent a coin, it's gone!

Comment: Not the answer I expected, but it does seem to fit well.  I like it.

Answer (score -3):

Okay, it's

> [Hymen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hymen)

When I'm bitten, you will suffer.

> Man genital is like a snake, when it 'bite' hymen, some woman will suffer.

When I'm precious, you will suffer no more.

> When decide to keep it, you will not suffering.

When I'm used, you will never see me again.

> If already bitten, you will never see your hymen again. ([actually you can](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_hymen))